# How can we validate a field based on another field value in the form?

Tags: sitecore-forms

In this form, i have to compare two fields(Mail,Confirm Mail). Whether this both email is same or not.if we typed incorrect email in confirm mail field. we have to show error message. so i created confirm email custom validation and assign to confirm form field.

In this confirm custom validation, i'm not able to get other form field value(mail Field).  how we can get the email value (other field value) in confirm custom validation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible out of the box nor is there a way to plugin an "entire form validator".

I think the best option at this time is to create a custom submit action and perform the validation in that action.

The execute method should return a boolean, if you return false, the submit pipeline will be cancelled.

```
protected override bool Execute(T data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample code for validation for this scenario

Comment: Is not possible solve through custom field validation?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it is not possible as the custom validation will only give access to the value of that field and not the entire form.